# The difference between 本屋さん and 本屋

Tags: meaning

Why 本屋 ends with -さん (本屋さん)?
Isn't 本屋 enough?  What's  the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the -さん is a polite suffix and could provide information about your relationship to the 本屋. For example, you are a customer, an employee, or are involved in business with it in some other way. Then you could use -さん to refer to 本屋 in a polite conversation.
Although I am not quite sure about whether this is a requirement, or it is generally simply possible to add the honorific without pragmatic change. Wikipedia refers to this use of the suffix as "use with workplace nouns", therefore there probably is a connection.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense now, thank you!